# Recylerview not visible in Android App

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have created a recyclerView in one of the fragments of my activity. And I am binding it to a dataset. I have set both the LinearLayoutManager and RecyclerView Adapter. My dataset is also getting created correctly and so is my Viewholder. There are no compilation warnings, no exceptions in my Logcat. I have checked the XML layouts for both fragment and the individual item and both are having all items set to Visible.

Yet my recyclerView is not showing in the fragment.

What are the common oversights resulting in recyclerView not being visible. Appreciate any guidance I can get on the matter.

Relevant Method initialising my recylerView is below:

```
private void loadMyPlacardView(View view){
        List<Post> postList = new ArrayList<>();
        RecyclerView placardsRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.fp_placards_recyclerView);
        LinearLayoutManager postsLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext());
        placardsRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        placardsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(postsLayoutManager);
        DataSnapshot dataSnapshot = FirebaseStorageUtils.postDataSnapshot;
        for (DataSnapshot singleSnapShot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Post thisPost = singleSnapShot.getValue(Post.class);
            postList.add(thisPost);
        }
        PlacardsRecyclerViewAdapter placardsRecyclerViewAdapter = new PlacardsRecyclerViewAdapter(postList);
        placardsRecyclerView.setAdapter(placardsRecyclerViewAdapter);
    }
```

Code for the RecyclerviewAdapter is here

```
public class PlacardsRecyclerViewAdapter 
extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlacardHolder> {
private static final String TAG = "PlacardsViewAdapter";
private  List<Post> listofPosts;

public PlacardsRecyclerViewAdapter(List <Post> list) {
    listofPosts = list;
}
@Override
    public PlacardHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){ 
View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.placard_item, parent, false);
                return new PlacardHolder(view);
           }
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PlacardHolder placard, int position) {
    Post currentPost = listofPosts.get(position);
    String username = currentPost.getUserName();
    placard.userName.setText(username);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listofPosts.size();
    }
}
```

Code for Recyclerviewholder as class PlacardHolder.java is below

```
public class PlacardHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
private static final String TAG = "PlacardsHolder";

public TextView userName;

public PlacardHolder(View view){
    super(view);
        this.userName = view.findViewById(R.id.pi_profile_name);
}
}
```

XML for the Placard Item is placard_item.xml below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/pi_profile_name"
        android:text="@string/default_username"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_weight="7"/></android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and code for fragment_placard.xml is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="testing recyclerview"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fp_placards_recyclerView"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The textview from the fragment_placard.xml is loading fine but not the recyclerview.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help if you could put some code in your question.

Comment: @ali73 - Added the code. Please review and help

Comment: Are you using Firebase Realtime Database?

Comment: @Shruti - Yes, but there is no change to the data. I am just loading it as it is from the current Data set.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh Firebase Listeners are ***asynchronous***; so even if you write the code to  load the data in postList before setting your adapter, the listener might not get called.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh did you get it?

Comment: @Shruti - your answer did not work, unfortunately... Thanks for helping

Comment: Can you show me your Firebase code to fetch data @AbhishekSingh?

Comment: @AbhishekSingh Check my updated ans, you need to notify like that.

Comment: @Shruti - Found the bug and posted in my answer below.. It was not in the Java code but in the XML instead. Thanks for helping. Much appreciate it.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh Cool! All the best with Firebase!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay! It is about ***Firebase***. You are not notifying your adapter after adding data to dataset. Do

```
if(placardsRecyclerViewAdapter != null)
    placardsRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

after adding data to `postList`.

**Updated**

Full structure:

```
private ValueEventListener postListener = null;

private void loadMyPlacardView(View view) {

    List<Post> postList = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView placardsRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.fp_placards_recyclerView);
    LinearLayoutManager postsLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext());
    placardsRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    placardsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(postsLayoutManager);
    PlacardsRecyclerViewAdapter placardsRecyclerViewAdapter = new PlacardsRecyclerViewAdapter(postList);
    placardsRecyclerView.setAdapter(placardsRecyclerViewAdapter);

    //Fetching data from Firebase
    postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if (dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Post thisPost = ds.getValue(Post.class);
                        postList.add(thisPost);
                    }
                    if(placardsRecyclerViewAdapter != null)
                        placardsRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //Now postList has data so notify adapter.
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                // Getting Post failed, log a message
                Log.e("DB error", "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            }
    };
    databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
}
```

Comment: i think we need `notifyDataSetChanged()` it when we are making changes to the `postList`  after creating our listview AFIK

Comment: @phpdroid True! But he fetching data from Firebase DB which is asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question. there were 2 bugs. First problem was in the placard_item.xml where I had declared the Constraintview as follows:

```
android:layout_height ="match parent"
```

because of this the layout was taking up the entire space in the screen. The second bug was that I had defined the TextView as below

```
android:layout_width = "0dp"
```

This was causing the TextView to disappear inside the recyclerview at run-time, although it was showing perfectly well in the "Design" view of my xml in AndroidStudio IDE. I am posting answer here in case someone else faces same issues. "ConstraintView" in general is proving hard to handle while working with Recyclerview. So going back to the simpler LinearLayout.